# In this case, How do i use char pointer?(SOCKET Programming in windows)

Tags: c, sockets, winsock, tcp, winsock2

attention under codes

SERVER.c

```
char* message = "hel";
send(clientsock, &message, 3, 0);
```

CLIENT.c

```
char** message = NULL;
messageLen = recv(clientsock, **message, 2, 0);
```

My plan is SERVER.c source in char* message = "hel" send to CLIENT.c source in char** message. but it doesn't work, what i do to my plan do ?

Server.c Full source

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PORT 1234
#define BACKLOG 10



int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

SOCKET sock, clientsock;
WSADATA wasData;
struct sockaddr_in sockinfo, clientinfo;
int clientsockSize;
char* message = "hel";


if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wasData) != 0) {  //int WSAStartup(WORD wVersionRequested, LPWSADATA lpWSAData);
    return 0;
}

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); // socket( AF_INET , type , protocol)

if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    return 1;
}

sockinfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
sockinfo.sin_port = htons(PORT); // 
sockinfo.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

if (bind(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&sockinfo, sizeof(sockinfo)) == SOCKET_ERROR) { // int bind (sock , (SOCKADDR*)&sockinfo , sizeof(sockinfo)) if true : return 0, else -1
    return 2;
}

if (listen(sock, BACKLOG) == SOCKET_ERROR) {  // Int listen ( SOCKET , backlog )
    return 3;
}


clientsockSize = sizeof(clientinfo);

printf("접속 대기중...\n");

clientsock = accept(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&clientinfo, &clientsockSize); 


if (clientsock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    return 4;
}

printf("Send your message >> ");

send(clientsock, &message, sizeof(message), 0);  

closesocket(sock);
closesocket(clientsock);

WSACleanup();

return -1;

}
```

CLIENT.c Full source

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#include <stdio.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

SOCKET clientsock;
WSADATA wasData;
struct sockaddr_in sockinfo;

char** message = NULL;

int messageLen;

if (argc != 3) {
    printf("Argument is not sufficient!\nInputed Argument >> %d", argc);
    exit(1);
}

if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wasData) != 0) {
    printf("Error >> Init WSAStartup(..)\n");
}

clientsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (clientsock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    printf("Error >> socket(..)\n");
memset(&sockinfo, 0, sizeof(sockinfo)); // 구조체 초기화

sockinfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
sockinfo.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
sockinfo.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);

if (connect(clientsock, (SOCKADDR*)&sockinfo, sizeof(sockinfo)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    printf("Error >> connect(..)\n");

messageLen = recv(clientsock, **message, sizeof(message) - 1, 0);
if (messageLen == -1)
    printf("Error >> recv(..)\n");

printf("Server say >> %s", message);
closesocket(clientsock);
WSACleanup();

}
```

Comment: Refer to other socket program related questions here. There are basic mistakes related to pointers which are covered already in other questions.

Answer (score 1):

**CLIENT SIDE**

You must use an allocated buffer to receive chars from socket.

You are using pointer to pointer with bo allocated memory

```
char** message = NULL;
```

You must use

```
char message[MAX_MSG_DIM] = {0};
```

or

```
char *message = malloc(MAX_MSG_DIM);
```

Take note that `recv` does not return when all character are received, but available chars only. This means that to receive the whole message from client `recv` could be called more then one. You must count received char to be sure if the whole message is arrived.

**SERVER SIDE**

To send message to client you wrote

```
send(clientsock, &message, sizeof(message), 0);
```

It is wrong. Firs of all you must pass the pointer of message and secondly size of is not the correct way to retrieve a string length. You must use `strlen` to do that.

```
send(clientsock, message, strlen(message)+1, 0);
```

I wrote `strlen(message)+1` due to the fact that, on your client side, you are not adding a `NULL` terminator on the received buffer. Then you must send it from server side.

Comment: You don't need to send a null terminator if you pay attention to the return value of `recv()`. It tells you how many bytes were actually received. Use that number when processing the bytes and don't exceed it. For instance, when passing the data to `printf()`, pass the length as well, then you don't need to null terminate the data: `printf("Server say >> %.*s", messageLen, message);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok, that's true but OP wrote `printf("Server say >> %s", message);` that need a `NULL` terminator. Really using `char message[MAX_MSG_DIM] = {0};` an for this specific case `NULL` terminator is already inside the buffer. What I meant is: I cannot wrote all possible solutions for OP. I tried to give him/her some hints to thing on to start to correct its code.